# Mac compile error, make: obj/droid-ios/mame/build/file2str: Permission denied

Tags: android, compilation, android-ndk

OS : macOS 10.13.4
NDK : rc9
I wanner to run mame in Android, here is the GitHub URL :   https://github.com/mrpostiga/imame4all/tree/master/Reloaded/trunk

but, when I want to make `.so` file, I get an error:

```
mkdir -p obj/droid-ios/mame/build
cp -R prec-build/file2str obj/droid-ios/mame/build 
Converting src/mame/layout/aristmk4.lay...
make: obj/droid-ios/mame/build/file2str: Permission denied
make: *** [obj/droid-ios/mame/mame/layout/aristmk4.lh] Error 1
```

Comment: How do you build?

Comment: `mkdir` is basically an execution command. Are you sure the user has permission? Can you create a directory there?